# spring boot integration test - database not autowired with @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have this sprig boot ( version 1.5.6) application that uses the following:

- spring boot starter data jpa (jpa repositories and entities)
- spring boot starter data gemfire (no repository or entities)
- spring boot starter data rest (for HAL support)

Now, I am creating the unit tests for this application. In one test case I have following annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = { "spring.cloud.enabled=false" })
```

The test initializes the jpa repository correctly and I am able to test the same.

Then I have another test with following annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyRestController.class)
```

This test sets up the Mockmvc but it does not initializes the JPA repositories. It only initialize the MVC part of configuration. But I need the JPA repositories to be initialized as well. I have test data setup with data.sql file which is loaded as in-memory H2 database. The error I am getting is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

I have tried multiple things which have not worked out:

- Using both annotations does not work as the class can have only one "BootstrapWith" annotation.
- @EnableJpaRepositories does not work
- @AutoConfigureTestDatabase does not work

I do see the following while the context initialization:

```
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
```

Now since spring is able to autowire the jpa repository in the first test and it works fine in the application, I think it should be able to autowire the repository in webMvc test case as well.

I could create a configuration file and initialize the entity manager, data source, etc in the test package but if there is a way to autowire things with spring, then I don't want to manage that configuration.

Please suggest.

Comment: i know it has already been answered but just to add few cent you can use @contextConfiguration to load the database related and other spring configuration it can include both xml and classes configuration files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see you have the `@WebMvcTest` annotation. That particular one is meant to test only the web layer, it doesn't load the whole application context, only the web context. You probably need to switch to `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to test the whole stack.

The way you do JPA tests with Spring Boot is using the `@DataJpaTest` annotation. It automatically configures everything, provided that you have an in-memory DB in the classpath (if you use maven, make sure it's in the "testing" scope). It also provides the `TestEntityManager`, which is an implementation of JPA's `EntityManager` interface with some useful features for testing.

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
pubic class EntityTest {
    @Autowired TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void saveShouldPersistData() throws Exception {
        User saved = entityManager.persistFlushFind(new User("username", "password"));
        assertNonNull(saved);
    }
}
```

And in your pom.xml you can add the H2 database (Spring Boot can configure Derby and HSQLDB automatically as well)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: And if you use gradle, use `testCompile('com.h2database:h2')` in your `dependencies`.